# ListView Layout Issues While Scrolling

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

In my Nativescript application I have built a ListView in which each list item contains a stack layout with a nested GridLayout. Here is an example of the XML.

```
    <ListView  row="2" items="{{ measurements }}" id="measurement-list" loaded="" itemTap="">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label class="date-seperator" text="{{header | dateShortDate}}" textWrap="true" visibility="{{ header ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"/>
                <GridLayout columns="8,*,10,*" rows="*, *" class="{{'measurement-item trend-' + MeasurementColor}}">
                    <Label class="{{'severity-' + MeasurementColor}}" col="0" rowSpan="2"  text="" />  
                    <WrapLayout col="1" orientation="horizontal" itemWidth="" itemHeight="">
                        <Label class="measurement-value" col="1" text="{{Value}}" />
                        <Label id="trend-arrow" class="{{'sm-arrow-' + TrendArrow }}" col="1" />                                
                    </WrapLayout>                                                                                               
                    <Label class="measurement-uom"   col="1" row="1" text="mg/dl"/>
                    <Label class="measurement-time"  col="3" row="0" text="{{Timestamp | dateTimeStamp}}"/>                
                </GridLayout>                    
            </StackLayout>                 
        </ListView.itemTemplate> 
    </ListView>
```

I'm having an issue though in which when I scroll the list view the layout of list items begins to distort and elements misalign or completely disappear. The list items with the layout issues also isn't consistent. If I scroll up and see a few items that a broken I can scroll back a few seconds later and they will be fine but other items in the list will look distorted. Any idea what would cause this or what I could use to get around it? Below is a screen shot of what I mean.

[image: Notice the timestamps, the 12:34 AM timestamp is aligned correctly. The others are either justified incorrectly or missing, even though the data for it is available!]

**EDIT**
I restructured the xml in the list view based on the accepted answers recommendations and the problem is now fixed. Below is the updated xml in case anyone runs into a similar problem.

```
<ListView  row="2" items="{{ measurements }}" id="measurement-list" loaded="" itemTap="">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label class="date-seperator" text="{{header | dateShortDate}}" textWrap="true" visibility="{{ header ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"/>
            <GridLayout columns="8,80,*,90" rows="*, *" class="{{'measurement-item trend-' + MeasurementColor}}">
                <Label rowSpan="2" col="0" class="{{'severity-' + MeasurementColor}}" text="" />                        
                    <Label row="0" col="1" horizontalAlignment="right" class="measurement-value" text="{{Value}}" />
                    <Label row="0" col="2" horizontalAlignment="left" class="{{'trend-arrow sm-arrow-' + TrendArrow }}" />                                                                                                          -->
                <Label row="1" col="1" horizontalAlignment="right" class="measurement-uom" text="{{ UOM | getUOMFromGlucoseType }}"/>
                <Label row="0" rowSpan="2" col="3" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="middle" class="measurement-time" text="{{Timestamp | dateTimeStamp}}"/>                        
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: My guess here is that you should control the items in your WrapLayout. Either give them fixed sizes via itemHeight and itemWidth or use another kind of layout.

Comment: Thank for the detailed comment! If you want to make it an answer I will try it out and mark it as the correct one of it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues. One is that for a GridLayout you need to account for each cell in the table - you haven't. e.g. row 1 col 3.

But the main reason why it's behaving this way is the way ListView works. ListView seems to measure the layout once during creation and then as you scroll, the objects are discarded and reused again for different underlying objects. So, e.g. if a label contained 4:29 once - the Label width is set to fit that. Next time ListView puts a longer text label in the same item - 11:34 - there's not enough space and listview decides not to display it. Solution? Set the width of the column explicitly.